# Correct type for source map files in script html tag

Tags: javascript, html, mime-types

when including a javascript library, i use to ad the `type="text/javascript"` as an attribute to the html `<script>` tag, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/js/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

I would like to know which one is the correct value to use when including a source map file like the one provided with the production version of [`underscore.js`](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't include the source maps manually with the HTML. The JS file does that automatically.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that :/ where do I have to put the source map? in the same folder that the js?

Comment: Yes. Or look in the console to see what file it tries to load.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Well, I don't know what to do with this question then, so, if you want, please answer it, and i'll mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks again...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if for any reason you will need to include such type of file I would suggest you to use

```
application/json
```

Here is what guys from getbootstrap.com are doing:

[image: getbootstrap.com uses application/json for map files]

Comment: This answer is not useful, yes the filetype of sourcemaps is application/json, but you don't request the file by yourself, the browser does that, if it finds `/*# sourceMappingURL=` at the end of the original js or css file, as @JJJ already mentioned.

Comment: @RiZKiT as it says *...if for any reason you would need to include such type...* I'm not here to ask *WHY* they need it, I'm here to provide an answer with *HOW* they can do what they want to do 